# Oracle Database 12c: Unable to resize system tablespace

Tags: oracle, configuration, database-size

#### Problem:

My java application is returning `ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment` errors for every insert

#### Cause:

After running:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dba_tablespace_usage_metrics 
ORDER BY used_percent desc;
```

I found that the `SYSTEM` datafile is 99.81% full (and is only 4MB for some reason).

#### Solution Attempts:

1. I turned autoextend on with

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE 
   DATAFILE '/home/user/oracle/orcl/system01.dbf' 
   AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 2048M 
   MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
   ```

   ...which executed fine, but did not increase the size.
2. I then tried to manually increase the size with:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE 
   DATAFILE '/home/user/oracle/orcl/system01.dbf' 
   RESIZE 2048M;
   ```

...which gave an error that the new size I was trying to use would end up truncating data. That makes no sense of course since the current size is 4MB. I also tried pasting in 2GB as bytes instead of "2048M" because I thought it may not understand "2048M". That gave the same error though.

What is the actual, working way to get rid of the `ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment` error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS` shows units in database blocks, not bytes. 4 MB is not enough for a SYSTEM tablespace. Most likely what you saw was 4M blocks, which is 32 GB with a 8K blocksize tablespace, and that is the maximum size of a datafile in a 8K smallfile tablespace. That is why your attempts had no effect.

You can add a new datafile to the tablespace, for example:

```
alter tablespace system add datafile '/home/user/oracle/orcl/system02.dbf' size 10m autoextend on next 10M maxsize unlimited;
```